# infoWindow on MarkerClusterer in OsmBonusPack?

Tags: android, osmdroid

Is there a possiblity to open a infoWindow with a click on a MarkerClusterer with OsmDroid + OsmBonusPack?

I want to display information about the different Markers which are inside the MarkerClusterer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Sub-class the RadiusMarkerClusterer (I assume you are using this one), and override the #renderer method.

Copy the RadiusMarkerClusterer.renderer. Then, just after the Marker is created:

```
Marker m = buildClusterMarker(cluster, mapView);
```

give to this Marker your InfoWindow:

```
m.setInfoWindow(myOwnInfoWindow)
```

You may have to sub-class the MarkerInfoWindow, depending on what you want to display exactly about the clustered markers.

Comment: Works well, thx! But I have problems filling the infoWindow with content. I made new class `public class ClusterInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow`. How can I access the title or subtitle of the clustered markers?

Comment: How can I access the title or subtitle of the clustered markers? => you can give a "related object" to a Marker. So give it its MarkerClusterer. Then, from the InfoWindow, you can access to its Marker, then to its related object (the MarkerClusterer), then to all its clustered markers (with myClusterer.getItems).

Comment: Thanks once again!! I solved it like this: "1. you can give a "related object" to a Marker. So give it its MarkerClusterer => `marker.setRelatedObject(cluster);` " -- "2. Then, from the InfoWindow, you can access to its Marker, then to its related object (the MarkerClusterer), then to all its clustered markers => `@Override public void onOpen(final Object item){ Marker marker = (Marker)item; StaticCluster selectedCluster = (StaticCluster)marker.getRelatedObject();`"